# Не импортируется Django

Tags: python, django, cmd, windows-10, импорт

Не импортируется Django . Вот ошибка:

```
    File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
        "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
    ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available
    on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate
    a virtual environment?
Полная ошибка:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    import django
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

P.S Скачал я джанго с помощью pip install django,до этого я скачал virtualenv и virtualenvwadder.

Comment: ОС я так понимаю Windows?

Comment: Да!Если , придется , закачаю linux!

Comment: @Taras используйте docker, вам же проще будет https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/#create-a-django-project

Comment: Другие варианты есть,я не понимаю как это делать.

Comment: Нет,когда я python manage.py migrate

Comment: Короче говоря,надо все пайтоны по удалять,а вообще желательно Ubuntu поставить,с этим я согласен.Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 3):

Это может произойти, если мы не будем использовать правильную версию PIP. Если у вас есть 2 версии Python ([python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) и [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x)), и вы хотите установить их поверх Python 3.x, вам нужно выбрать `pip3` из абсолютного пути.

Самый простой способ - выбрать правильную версию pip из абсолютного пути, как показано ниже:

```
pip3 install django
```

или

```
C:\Python34\Scripts>pip3 install django
```

Comment: У меня установлен джанго там где и у вас,только у меня Python27 установлен ( не знаю в чём отличие ). Но если написать pip install django то покажет Requirement already satisfied: django in c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages.

Comment: Python у меня самый новый, а pip install django выдаёт это , да.

Comment: Если посмотреть через панель управление, там будет 3.6.2 (32 -bit)

Comment: Да,также. Может ошибка в том что у меня джанго в двух отдельных папок храниться?

Comment: У меня джанго установлен и в Pycharm и в C:\Python34\Scripts

Answer (score 0):

Если работаешь через виртуальную среду, то следует сначала запустить сервер, после этого у меня все отлично работало, такой порядок даже указан в книги Винсента Уильимса, которая про Джанго (хз как правильно писать регалии его).

Answer (score -3):

Вначале нужно прописать, "python":
python manage.py runserver